# Problems with bib containing wiki and book reference

Tags: bibtex

I wrote a report in latex before with a bib file, and it worked properly. However, I am writing a new report in Latex, and I have the references in a seperate bib file, but this report is not working. The only main difference is that I use a book and wikipedia as a references instead of mostly articles

I am using Texworks on Windows. After compiling the bib to generate a bbl, when I compile the tex file with: pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex. When I tried that, the 'References' section shows up at the end, but I do not see the references, such as

1. Reinhard, D.A. Case Study
   I also do not see the citation in the paper

Here is the MWE: The tex is:

```
\documentclass{article}  
%\usepackage{url,apacite}  - had problems regardless if I included this or not
%\bibliographystyle{apacite} - same as above
\begin{document}  
Alpha particles \cite{wikip} (named \cite{Comp} after and denoted by the first letter     in the
Greek alphabet,\[\alpha\]) consist of two protons and two neutrons bound
together.
This means that an particle is a helium nucleus. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{BibName}

\end{document}
```

The bib for the first report was:

```
@article{example,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
```

The bib for my 2nd  report is:

```
@misc{wikip,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title = "Pen --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
   year = "2014",
   url = "\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen}",
   note = "[Online; accessed 14-December-2014]"
 }


@book{Comp,
   author = "Rub",
   title = "Com",
   year = "1997",
   publisher = "John Wiley & Sons, Inc.",
    address   = "New York, New York"
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: I deleted biblatex and footmisc tabs which don't seem related.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors; David Carlisle has already pointed out some of them in the comments.

- You must "escape" the `&` symbol in the publisher field, i.e., write `\&`.
- Since it looks like you want to use the `apacite` package and associated bibliography style, don't encase a URL string in `\url{...}`. Instead, just write `url = "...",`.
- Do fix the placement of the curly braces in the `title` field of the entry "wikip".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{BibName.bib}
@misc{wikip,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title = "Pen --- {Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia}",
   year = "2014",
   url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen",
   note = "Accessed 14-December-2014"
 }
@book{Comp,
   author = "Rub",
   title = "Com",
   year = "1997",
   publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.",
    address   = "New York, New York"
 }    
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}  
\cite{wikip} 

\cite{Comp}
\bibliography{BibName}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
 John Wiley & Sons,
```

has to be

```
 John Wiley \& Sons,
```

otherwise you will get an error on the `&` but then latex bibtex latex latex should produce the image shown. (Your description sounded like you ran bibtex first which would be incorrect)

Comment: I made that change and it still won't work. I ran it pdflatex + biblatex + pdflatex+ pdflatex

Comment: @user4352158 biblatex is not a program, your document is not using biblatex at all but bibtex changing `&` to `\&` is the only change I made to your posted code to produce the image I showed. if it didn't work then you did something wrong but can't say unless you show the exact error from the log

Comment: the bib file must be called `BibName.bib` @user4352158

Comment: @user4352158 you must first delete the generated .bbl file with the `&` as it will generate errors and prevent latex completing.